# What attacks are considered to be Incoming Projectiles?

Tags: dota-2, dota

On *playdota.com* I've read that

1. Incoming projectiles before **windrun** is activated will not be evaded.
2. AM, QOP, etc. can dodge incoming projectiles with blink.

**So I'm wondering what it actually meant by incoming projectiles?**

Is ranged attack (missile) considered incoming projectile? What spells are considered to be incoming projectiles in DotA?

Comment: You know that you can just edit questions instead of deleting and reposting them, right?

Comment: @YiJiang I first deleted the question because I thought it was bad and didn't deserve to be here. But on second thought I decided to elaborate my question and repost it again, since Google suggested that no one has ever asked this before and the answer can be found nowhere. I apologise for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Windrunner's ability only dodges ranged autoattack projectiles. If it says otherwise, it's wrong.

Projectile is a mechanics term that includes ranged autoattacks and targeted spells that are a missile. Most projectiles can be "disjointed" by blinking, while others cannot.

Off the top of my head, Sven's Storm Hammer and Windrunner's Shackleshot are spells that cannot be dodged by blinking or teleporting. There are probably others.

Others such as VS's stun, Sniper's ultimate, etc. can be dodged with a Blink Dagger, Teleport Scroll, or similar spells that contain a disjoint such as Mirana's leap or QoP/AM's Blinks.

Comment: Tinker's missiles, Necrolyte's Death pulses probably fall under this category as well.